# The POM for unknown.binary:AbsoluteLayout:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: java, maven, database-connection

Can anyone please tell what I am doing wrong here.
I am trying to create the student database management system for my practice but I am stuck here. Here I am trying to connect the java file with mysql on local server but getting this error.

**This is the code**

```
try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            
            sqlConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dataConn,username,password);
            String str = "insert into studentdata(StudentID,FirstName,LastName,Address,Gender,Mobile,"
                    + "Math,Game,DataSci,Analysis,Graphic,DataBase1,Science,English)values"
                    + "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            pst = sqlConn.prepareStatement(str);
            
            pst.setString(1, txtStudentID.getText());
            pst.setString(2, txtFirstName.getText());
            pst.setString(3, txtLastName.getText());
            pst.setString(4, txtAddress.getText());
            pst.setString(5, (String) cboGender.getSelectedItem());
            pst.setString(6, txtMobile.getText());
            pst.setString(7, (String) cboMaths.getSelectedItem());
            pst.setString(8, (String) cboGames.getSelectedItem());
            pst.setString(9, (String) cboDataSci.getSelectedItem());
            pst.setString(10, (String) cboAnalysis.getSelectedItem());
            pst.setString(11, (String) cboGraphic.getSelectedItem());
            pst.setString(12, (String) cboDataBase.getSelectedItem());
            pst.setString(13, (String) cboScience.getSelectedItem());
            pst.setString(14, (String) cboEnglish.getSelectedItem());
            int resu = pst.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("result: " + resu);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Student Record Added");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
          
   java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(StudentDBMS.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

**This is my POM file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>StudentDBMS</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>AbsoluteLayout</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

[This is the location of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uN6T.png)

**console showing error**

```
The POM for unknown.binary:AbsoluteLayout:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

--- exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) @ StudentDBMS ---
Apr 20, 2021 12:36:04 AM StudentDBMS.StudentDBMS btnAddNewActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at StudentDBMS.StudentDBMS.btnAddNewActionPerformed(StudentDBMS.java:400)
    at StudentDBMS.StudentDBMS.access$100(StudentDBMS.java:26)
    at StudentDBMS.StudentDBMS$2.actionPerformed(StudentDBMS.java:130)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4955635/927493 about how to handle local JAR files.